# IMAP Migration Perhaps With PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a requirement for a client to move a large set of IMAP mailboxes from one server to another.

You would think given that email is hugely popular and migration occurrences must happen all the time that a tool would exist to help migrate from one server to another, you'd be hugely surprised to also learn...there is not.

As an agency we need to take care of these migrations for our clients so we're trying to nail down a process that works and that we will be confident in using going forward.

Our hosting company seems to have even less of an idea than we do as to what we could do, so i'm turning to stack and it's users.

Somethings I know already and don't want to hear:

Manual syncing of IMAP accounts back to the server by the client (relying on this for over 50 mailboxes is just to cumbersome)

Somethings I know and seem useful:

There are PHP scripts out there to connect to imap mail servers and migrate (these interest me since PHP is my main prog language). However, i've had no luck so far with any I have tried. I need IMAP folders to also be migrated (i.e Sent, Custom folders etc) I need read or unread status to remain intact.

I'll update this post if I think of anything else I can add to it.

So, what do you think?

Comment: What is important to know to answer: What kind of access do you have to both mail servers and which kind of software are they running. Normally just moving the e-mails at the back-end is easier but we also use PHP software in a portal which also works. Mostly a move from sysadmins is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel?

Use "Imapsync": an IMAP migration tool

Answer (score 0):

There is an old but still working tool called [imapcopy](http://home.arcor.de/armin.diehl/imapcopy/imapcopy.html). It consist of two files, an exe and a configuration file. I had successfuly migrated my mail boxes. It does not keep folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using IMAPSync on a powerful box and it was very slow with large inboxes. I went with a solution called dropmyemail.com - Fantastic service. Backs your emails up daily and then you simply click Migrate and it does the rest. They have a free trial too :)